# Connected through VNC with Xfce enviroment, Thunar doesn't open files. I can open them with Nautilus, but then, I can't "Open In Terminal"

Tags: xfce, remote-access, thunar

So, basically what the title says.

I finanlly achieved to connect to the desktop of my Uni but I can't open files with Thunar, and when I change the "preferred application" to Nautilus, I just can't open in terminal.

Any Help?

Comment: What OS & release are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

When opening a file, either via the main menu, via the file's context menu, by double-clicking on it or by hitting the enter key, the file manager performs the default action for that file type.

The default file open mode is double-clicking but you can set Thunar preferences so that a single click will execute the default action.

To execute actions other than the default action for a file, select the file in question, then choose the desired action from the Open With choices available from the File menu or the right-click context menu.

To add actions associated with a file type, perform the following steps:

```
In the main area, select a file of the type to which you want to add an action.

Choose File → Open With → Open With Other Application... from the main menu.

Either choose an application from the list or select Use a custom command and browse to the program with which you wish to open this type.
```

The action you have chosen is now added to the list of Recommended Applications for that particular file type. If you enabled the Use as default for this kind of file option or there was no prior action associated with the type, the newly added action becomes the default.

You may also add actions using the Open With pick list under File → Properties....

To modify the actions associated with a file or file type, perform the following steps:

```
In the main area, select a file of the type for which you want to modify the action.

Choose File → Properties... from the main menu.

Select the new default action by choosing one of the recommended applications in the Open With pick list or add a new action by choosing Other Application... and selecting an application in the Open With dialog.
```

The Properties dialog shows more information about any file or folder in the file manager. To open the Properties window, perform the following steps:

```
Select the file or folder you want to examine or change. You can select multiple items at once and display the properties that are common to them all.
Do one of the following:

Choose File → Properties... from the main menu.

Right-click the item and choose Properties... from the context menu.

Press Alt-Return.
```

If there are no files or folders selected, right-clicking anywhere on the whitespace or performing any of the other actions listed above will present the context menu of the current folder that you are viewing.

There are three or four tabs in the Properties dialog that give you access to the following information or actions:
General

```
For folders:
   
See the total size of all the files in the current folder and all subfolders.

View a Usage slider which displays used and free space on the current partition.

For files:
    The ability to change the default Open With action for this file and other files of the same type.

    File type and size.
```

Emblems

```
Customize a particular file or folder's icon by adding an emblem.
To add custom emblems, add your icons to the 'emblems' directories of your current icon theme, for each size. E.g: ~/.icons/$theme/*/emblems/
```

Permissions

```
Change the UNIX file permissions for a file or folder.
```

Image

```
Only present for graphics files. View the image size in pixels (and other metadata, if available).
```

There are several ways to select files in Thunar.

```
To select a single file, you can simply click on it with the left mouse button.

You can select multiple files by holding down the Ctrl key and clicking on the files, or holding down the Shift key to select a range of files.

You can also select multiple files and folders by using the mouse to drag a selection box over them. Note: If you are using View as a Detailed List in the Main Area, you must first position the mouse over a file/folder name (not in the whitespace) before dragging.

You can also select files by providing a pattern with the keyboard shortcut Ctrl-S or from the main menu Edit → Select pattern.... For example, to select all text files, hit Ctrl-S and enter “*.txt” in the dialog.

If you want to find a single file and know the beginning of the filename, simply start entering the filename in the view. A text box will appear in the bottom right corner and an incremental search will be performed. The first file that matches what you type will be selected. If there are multiple files names beginning with the same letters, continuing to type the name you're looking for will narrow your search down until the file you want is selected.
```

Other options are Select all Files and Invert Selection, which can be found in the Edit menu.

Comment: Hi! And REALLY REALLY thank you for your answer. Although, I just got a more serious problem, when I was trying to fix it, I changed something and then Couldn't connect (Grey Screen + X mouse). Have been trying the whole day (almost sleepless) to fix it with no results... As soon as I fix it (hopefully I will lol), I will check this out. U can't imagine how frustrated I am